# How to compress a size of 1024*1024*1024*4 sparse array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a sparse array which is size of 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 4.  This array's item is byte. So the memory for the array is 4G. It is a sparse array, that is, non-zero item only about 600M. Hopefully, a storage structure can be proposed to compress the sparse array (compressed to 2 ~ 3G), and have good access speed.

Comment: What's your current solution like?

Comment: I would implement a sparse array as an associative array, as a hash table.  I would take the indices (four of them, in your case), hash them together, then search a hash chain, as usual.  Or I would do a web search on "sparse array" to see what others have done.

Answer (score 1):

The suitable representation depends on what operations is desired on the sparse array. The general approach is to store the locations of non-zero items and their values in a data structure.

One option is to use a hash table.

```
enum {NumDimensons = 4};
struct ArrayLocation {
  int16_t location[NumDimensions];
};

typedef uint8_t ArrayValue;

// Hash Table with key as ArrayLocation and value as ArrayValue
```

With hash table operations like `get()` and `put()` are straightforward, but iteration is not. If iteration is important, one option is to use a binary search tree.